# Android enable hint for @null background

Tags: android, android-layout

i'm after set `@null` for `EditText` thats hint disable and i can not enable that

[image]

xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#e67e22"
        >
    <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                >
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".42"/>
            <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/username"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="43dp"
                    android:layout_weight="6"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:hint="@string/username_hint"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:background="@null"
                    />
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".42"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            >
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".42"/>
        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="43dp"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:hint="@string/password_hint"
                android:password="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:background="@null"
                />
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".42"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why did You set the background as null?

Comment: Quick question: Why do you need to set the background as null? What happens if you just don't use that attribute or set it to transparent?

Comment: this problem not occur for background null,make it android:textColorHint="#000000"

Comment: @Shobhit Puri i'm like skype theme and i want to set like with that

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the issue for the above xml. It works well. However try to set hint color, may be thats the issue. `android:textColorHint="#666"` Also check if the `hint` String resource is not `Empty String`